# jQuery get substring from string having start and end substrings of substring

Tags: jquery, regex, string, substring

So I have string, lets say this one:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

And lets say that there could be any jumping animal, not only fox, so the string could be different. And I need to get the part of it, lets say this one

> brown fox jumps

I know that my string starts with "brown" and ends with "jumps" so I suppose I need some regex to solve this.

I would also be very thankful if someone would explain the structure of writing regex to me, because so far I don't get it.

Comment: @guradio nothing, I don't know what to do

Comment: [`/brown.*jumps/`](https://regex101.com/r/lG5zE1/1) - simplest regex ( where `.` matches almost any character except newline.... and `*` for `0` or more repetition .... use `+` if you want `1` or more repetition)

Comment: Why do you need to take "brown" and not "quick" *(as it is an adjective too)*? is "brown" always here? "The quick brown snail jumps over the lazy frog"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the word in between would be easiest one.

```
/(brown.*jumps)/i
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[RegEx Tester](https://regex101.com/r/aG0cC5/6)

Or if you like to select the animal as single word too:

```
/(brown (.*) jumps)/i
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[RegEx Tester](https://regex101.com/r/aG0cC5/5)

Comment: why did you add the space in your pattern.?  `.` matches any character except new line.

Comment: You're right. It is not needed in the first example. In the second one it is *needed* to prevent the second match group to have spaces in it. On the first you could remove it, yes. @mkHun I've updated the first example.